# Auto complete in VC++

Tags: visual-c++

I am using visual c++ 2008 professional version. I know the dot magic that after put the dot after a variable, vs automatically displays possible member functions.

Can visual c++ display the names under current cursor point? E.g after type `m_`, vs displays all the variables starting with `m_` for me to choose?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know VS2010 does it automatically, but you can force it with CTRL+SPACE.

Comment: he is asking for text autocomplete. @David nope you cant, I heard that somewhere in the future they may support it though.

Comment: @Reno --yes, that is what I was talking about.  In VS2008/C++/CLR, if you type a portion of a variable name and hit `CTRL+SPACE`, you will get a list of close matches, including the variable name you're looking for.  I think you're talking about VS2010/C++/CLR where Microsoft admittingly released it with no IntelliSense support (refer to the outrage at http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/459187/intellisense-unavailable-for-c-cli)